# Custom error message not returning custom message from javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this javascript:

```
               $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/SaveTable2",
                    data: "{smallTablesTable:'" + JSON.stringify(smalltablesHot.getData()) + "',locationsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(locationsHot.getData()) + "',assetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(assetsHot.getData()) +
                        "',costCenterBudgetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(costCenterBudgetsHot.getData()) + "',employeesTable:'" + JSON.stringify(employeesHot.getData()) + "',laborCraftsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(laborcraftsHot.getData()) +
                        "',tasksTable:'" + JSON.stringify(tasksHot.getData()) + "',partsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(partsHot.getData()) + "',vendorsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(vendorsHot.getData()) +
                        "',stockroomPartsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(stockroompartsHot.getData()) + "',toolsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(toolsHot.getData()) + "',facilityID:'" + facID +
                        "',locSuffix:'" + document.getElementById('tbLocSuffix').value + "',ccPrefix:'" + document.getElementById('tbCCPrefix').value + "',locRemoveAfter:'" +
                        document.getElementById('cbLocRemoveSuffix').checked + "',ccRemoveAfter:'" + document.getElementById('cbCCRemovePrefix').checked +
                        "',workOrderMastersTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womsHot.getData()) +
                        "',workOrderMasterAssetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womAssetsHot.getData()) + "',workOrderMasterLaborTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womLaborHot.getData()) +
                        "',workOrderMasterStockroomPartsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womStockroomPartsHot.getData()) + "',workOrderMasterToolsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womToolsHot.getData()) + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var final = data.d;
                        if (final.replace("\r\n", "").replace(";", "").length == 0) {
                            final = "No data to import";
                        }
                        document.getElementById("hdResults").value = final;
                        alert("Data Imported Successfully. Check Log File.");
                        doPostBack = true;
                    },
                    error: function (request, error) {
                        var errorMsg = request.responseJSON.Message.split(';')[0];
                        if (request.responseJSON.Message.split(';').length > 1) {
                            var errorTbl = request.responseJSON.Message.split(';')[1];
                            HitTabButton(errorTbl);
                        }

                        alert("ERROR - Import Table Failed: " + errorMsg);
                    }
                });
```

Which calls this c# method:

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string SaveTable2(string smallTablesTable, string locationsTable, string assetsTable, string costCenterBudgetsTable,
            string employeesTable, string laborCraftsTable, string tasksTable, string partsTable, string vendorsTable,
            string stockroomPartsTable, string toolsTable, string facilityID, string locSuffix, 
            string ccPrefix, string locRemoveAfter, string ccRemoveAfter, string workOrderMastersTable, 
            string workOrderMasterAssetsTable, string workOrderMasterLaborTable,
            string workOrderMasterStockroomPartsTable, string workOrderMasterToolsTable)
        {
            throw new Exception("Required Columns cannot be blank.);
        }
```

I cleared out a lot of code. This all works fine when i run it in visual studio, but when i publish and put the site up on my production server, the javascript `request.responseJSON.Message` changes from "Required Columns cannot be blank." to "There was an error processing the request. Is there something i need to add in the web.config? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated and should not be used anymore (it creates a poor user experience by freezing the browser UI. Users may think the browser has crashed if the AJAX call takes longer than expected. It also stops your code doing anything else useful while waiting for the server). In any case since you're using "success" and "error" callbacks correctly, you should have no need for a synchronous request.

Comment: Anyway, there is not enough detail to answer your question. "There was an error processing the request" could be a symptom of 1000 different things. We cannot advise you what to do based on that. Does your application log exceptions? If so, check the server logs to try and find out a more specific message.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. I will check if there is a way to get a better log of the exception.

Comment: After adding logging, the log from the backend code gives me the proper exception message, but still getting the generic "There was an error processing the request." when deployed. Any ideas why this is happening? @ADyson

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I wouldn't expect the application to give away the real error message to the AJAX client - that could lead to inadvertent leakage of security-critical information. So web applications generally obfuscate the error in this way. If you can get proper information from your log, then what's the issue? Are you saying the log, when deployed to the server, doesn't report a useful message? It's unclear. Please give us a more precise description of what is happening.

Comment: The message in the log is exactly what the end user needs to see. "Required Columns cannot be blank." It also say the row number and column name. I need the end user to see this error message. When I run through visual studio, the alert reads correctly, but when deployed, the alert is generic. I just need to know how to get the error message to pass while deployed. @ADyson

Comment: That sounds like a validation error, rather than an unexpected problem leading to a crash. In this case you've deliberately created a crash yourself by throwing a new exception. That's not a good pattern to use for data validation. Exceptions are supposed to be for unusual situations (even ones you could sometimes anticipate, such as a network outage). What HTTP status is your app returning in that scenario? 500 I would guess? For a validation error I'd expect it to return a 400 (Bad Request) status to the client, with the error message in the body of the response, and not throw an exception.

Comment: But because you _are_ throwing an exception for this little problem, then maybe the issue is that your server is set not to show exception details to remote clients. That's pretty standard config in asp.net applications (usually set in the web.config and/or IIS settings) - and for good reason. I would not advocate turning it off, because when you get a real exception it might accidentally spill out technical info which could be of use to a malicious user. Instead, implement a different way of indicating an anticipated validation error to the client, as I've just mentioned.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I need to handle the message and show the user in a different way other than creating an exception. It is a 500 error. I will modify the program to handle the error within the ajax success. Thanks for the reply. @ADyson

Comment: A 400 status will still show up as an error from Ajax's perspective. The important thing is you get more control, server side, over how you issue the message. I see you managed to make a way to do it, below, although it's not technically issuing an error code any more, it will probably serve your purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestions from ADyson, here is the solution i came up with:

Instead of creating an exception, i returned a message. Changed Javascript to this:

```
             $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/SaveTable2",
                    data: "{smallTablesTable:'" + JSON.stringify(smalltablesHot.getData()) + "',locationsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(locationsHot.getData()) + "',assetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(assetsHot.getData()) +
                        "',costCenterBudgetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(costCenterBudgetsHot.getData()) + "',employeesTable:'" + JSON.stringify(employeesHot.getData()) + "',laborCraftsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(laborcraftsHot.getData()) +
                        "',tasksTable:'" + JSON.stringify(tasksHot.getData()) + "',partsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(partsHot.getData()) + "',vendorsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(vendorsHot.getData()) +
                        "',stockroomPartsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(stockroompartsHot.getData()) + "',toolsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(toolsHot.getData()) + "',facilityID:'" + facID +
                        "',locSuffix:'" + document.getElementById('tbLocSuffix').value + "',ccPrefix:'" + document.getElementById('tbCCPrefix').value + "',locRemoveAfter:'" +
                        document.getElementById('cbLocRemoveSuffix').checked + "',ccRemoveAfter:'" + document.getElementById('cbCCRemovePrefix').checked +
                        "',workOrderMastersTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womsHot.getData()) +
                        "',workOrderMasterAssetsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womAssetsHot.getData()) + "',workOrderMasterLaborTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womLaborHot.getData()) +
                        "',workOrderMasterStockroomPartsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womStockroomPartsHot.getData()) + "',workOrderMasterToolsTable:'" + JSON.stringify(womToolsHot.getData()) + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var final = data.d;
                        if (final.startsWith("ERROR:")) {
                            doPostBack = false;
                            var finalMsg = final.replace("ERROR:", "");
                            alert("ERROR - Import Table Failed: " + finalMsg);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (final.replace("\r\n", "").replace(";", "").length == 0) {
                                final = "No data to import";
                            }
                            document.getElementById("hdResults").value = final;
                            alert("Data Imported Successfully. Check Log File.");
                            doPostBack = true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (request, error) {
                        var errorMsg = request.responseJSON.Message.split(';')[0];
                        if (request.responseJSON.Message.split(';').length > 1) {
                            var errorTbl = request.responseJSON.Message.split(';')[1];
                            HitTabButton(errorTbl);
                        }

                        alert("ERROR - Import Table Failed: " + errorMsg);
                    }
                });
```

And C# method like so:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string SaveTable2(string smallTablesTable, string locationsTable, string assetsTable, string costCenterBudgetsTable,
            string employeesTable, string laborCraftsTable, string tasksTable, string partsTable, string vendorsTable,
            string stockroomPartsTable, string toolsTable, string facilityID, string locSuffix, 
            string ccPrefix, string locRemoveAfter, string ccRemoveAfter, string workOrderMastersTable, 
            string workOrderMasterAssetsTable, string workOrderMasterLaborTable,
            string workOrderMasterStockroomPartsTable, string workOrderMasterToolsTable)
        {
            return "ERROR:Required Columns cannot be blank.";
        }
```